# How do you make CMake print *all* commands not just build commands?

Tags: cmake

So you can use the VERBOSE option to get CMake to print all the compiler command lines to the console as it builds, but that doesn't seem to have any effect on other commands that aren't compiler commands, e.g. this `execute_process` command:

```
  execute_process(
    COMMAND ${_TEST_EXECUTOR} "${_TEST_EXECUTABLE}" --gtest_list_tests
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${_TEST_WORKING_DIR}"
    TIMEOUT ${_TEST_DISCOVERY_TIMEOUT}
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE output
    RESULT_VARIABLE result
  )
```

It's actually part of the google test module in CMake.  I had an issue where I needed to track the exact command line that was being executed. I was able to but only by manually hacking the files. If I had just been able to spew all the commands CMake was executing it would have been much much quicker.

Is there some way to do that in CMake?

Comment: Do you want the verbose output of the `_TEST_EXECUTOR`? This will vary by whatever `COMMAND` is being run, and you have to manually insert the verbose option for that **specific** command, for each command.

Comment: Yeah I want to see the actual command line execute_process is running.  I can't add the verbose option here as its not my code, its in the Google Test CMake module, i actually had to copy that file, edit that one, and then hack my file to use the local copy (and this was *after* I'd spent ages tracking down the execute_process command that was running my test).  it would have saved tons of time if I could just see all the commands that CMake was running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the commands in [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/execute_process.html#command:execute_process) printed, you can set *where* you want them printed individually, in each `execute_process` command using `COMMAND_ECHO`:

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND ${_TEST_EXECUTOR} "${_TEST_EXECUTABLE}" --gtest_list_tests
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${_TEST_WORKING_DIR}"
    TIMEOUT ${_TEST_DISCOVERY_TIMEOUT}
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE output
    RESULT_VARIABLE result
    COMMAND_ECHO STDOUT
  )
```

or universally for all `execute_process` commands throughout your CMake project by setting this variable in your top-level CMake file:

```
set(CMAKE_EXECUTE_PROCESS_COMMAND_ECHO STDOUT)
```

These features are available in CMake versions 3.15 and above.

---

For what it's worth, you can also get the full printout of **every** command CMake runs (with expanded CMake variables) using the `cmake` [command line option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/manual/cmake.1.html#options):

```
cmake --trace-expand ..
```

but this may be much more verbosity than you're looking for.